# Monte Carlo annealing method for finding a root of a function

Tags: roots, monte-carlo

I want to find a root of a function such that 
$ \frac{constant\ value}{f(x)} = 1.0$. The function is not already known, but it is function of some parameters which simulated numerically. The procedure is to simulate the phenomena in which $f(x)$ is unknown, find value of  for $f(x_i), i=1,n$ and based on $f_i$ try to find the root of $f(x)$. It can be done by bisection of secant method, but in some situation it is unstable. My question is if Monte Carlo method (annealing or other methods) can be used for this kind of problems, if not which method would be appropriate.

Comment: You can do something like stochastic gradient descent if you think the stochasticity will help.

Comment: Can you please introduce a references?